# Nginx regexp to capture long random digits

Tags: regex, nginx

I'd like to weed out some junk requests like:

```
/path/to/%4444
/path/to/%44444445555555
/path/to/%44444445555555%6666666
```

I tried different settings like

```
location ^~ /path/to/[\%]([0-9] {3})  {
       return 404;
      }
```

or

```
location ^~ /path/to/([\%])([0-9] {3})  {
       return 404;
      }
```

But nginx does not restart. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried something like `/path/to/\%[0-9]+(\%[0-9]+)*` ? I don't know the regex constructs of niginx, nor how its delimited in the source, but it should be along those lines.

Comment: /path/to/\%\d{3} seems to work. Not sure about niginx though

Comment: `%44` in your request decoded to letter `D` before nginx looks for location. If you really want percent in your request you should encode it as `%25`

Comment: Btw, what is real problem you tries to solve?

Comment: @AlexeyTen It's a ddos attack vector that I'm trying to deny.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, why is space between [0-9] and {3} in you regexp, bun nging not restart, because:

> matching of a variable against a regular expression using the “~” (for case-sensitive matching) and “~*” (for case-insensitive matching) operators. Regular expressions can contain captures that are made available for later reuse in the $1..$9 variables. Negative operators “!~” and “!~*” are also available. If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes. ([nginx_docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html))

Just escape your regex by "". Like

```
location "^~ /path/to/[\%]([0-9] {3})"  {
   return 404;
  }
```